# Scrapy shell fetch response.css returns []

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning to scrape using scrapy. I would like to get some information about this medicine: https://www.apotheken-umschau.de/medikamente/beipackzettel/azithromycin-al-250-mg-filmtabletten-1805007.html
Before writing a spider in Python, I began with the headline using scrapy shell:

```
<h1 class="headline mb-3 fw-bolder">Beipackzettel von AZITHROMYCIN AL 250 mg Filmtabletten</h1>
```

and tried:

```
 fetch('https://www.apotheken-umschau.de/medikamente/beipackzettel/azithromycin-al-250-mg-filmtabletten-1805007.html')
```

then:

```
response.css('h1.headline mb-3 fw-bolder').getall()
```

Any idea why I get `[]`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an empty list is because your css selector is incorrect.  When using css selectors words seperated by spaces in the class attribute should be seperated by periods in the selector.

for example:

```
>>> response.css('h1.headline.mb-3.fw-bolder').getall()
['<h1 class="headline mb-3 fw-bolder">Beipackzettel von AZITHROMYCIN AL 250 mg Filmtabletten</h1>']
```

As you can see simply replacing the spaces with `.` gets you the element.

Since there is only one `h1` element though your selector could be simplified to just:

```
>>> response.css('h1::text').getall()
['Beipackzettel von AZITHROMYCIN AL 250 mg Filmtabletten']
```

Or you could use `xpath` like this:

```
response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
response.css('h1.headline ::text').getall()
```

Output:

```
['Beipackzettel von AZITHROMYCIN AL 250 mg Filmtabletten']
```